# How to refresh Cart using PHTML file with AJAX Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, ajax

In following File, there is a file "reload.php"

But i want to use "myajaxcart.phtml" in Magento, How ??

Is it possible to use .phtml there, as magento doesn't allow direct access to .phtml files ??

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 200);
</script>
```

I want like this :

```
$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('myajaxcart.phtml').fadeIn("slow");
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a standalone PHP file is not right way. You should be following the MVC structure of Magento.

AOE made a module that loosely does what you need it to do (ie. render out a block to be used for AJAX calls). It opens a little bit of a minefield in terms of security as potentially any block can be loaded, but you can add some appropriate filters to prevent issues.

There is a repo here, https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Static

The basic principle relies on a simple block of code within the main controller,

```
$this->loadLayout();
$layout = $this->getLayout();

$requestedBlockNames = $this->getRequest()->getParam('getBlocks');
if (is_array($requestedBlockNames)) {
  foreach ($requestedBlockNames as $id => $requestedBlockName) {
    $tmpBlock = $layout->getBlock($requestedBlockName);
    if ($tmpBlock) {
      $response['blocks'][$id] = $tmpBlock->toHtml();
    } else {
      $response['blocks'][$id] = 'BLOCK NOT FOUND';
    }
  }
}
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($response));
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento is implemented with the MVC pattern, this means Models, Views and Controllers are separated. All `.phtml` files in Magento are party of the view and can not be directly accessed, only controllers are accessible from outside, which themselfes render the view including the `.phtml` file.

So for your case create a simple controller, if there is not already one who renders the `myajaxcart.phtml`. If you're new in implementing controllers and associating views have a look in [the layout.xml tutorial on magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)